# rails How to update user attribute with Model.object from different controller on :create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to update(add or substract) to User.points_balance the value of Point.point_moving

I need to get the user from Point.user_id (user is not logged in)

I do not get error messages, the points are created but User.points_balance is not updated.

my points.controller

```
def create
  @point = Point.new(point_params)
  @point.save
  @user = User.find(params[@point.user_id])
  if user && user.increment(:points_balance, by = @point.points_moving) 
  respond_to do |format| 
   format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Saved.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
 end
end
```

Question update:
Having so much trouble to do this and cant figure out why., how about this?

I have Points controller with :user_id and :points_moving
I have Users controller with :points_balance that needs to be updated(add/substract) Point.points_moving value.

How should i do to create a separate method that updates User.points_balance (adding or substracting the value of Point.point_moving) and then call the method from the Points controller on :create ?

Hoping this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

Notice you're using `user.increment`. When you should increment `@user`

```
def create
  @point = Point.new(point_params)
  @point.save
  @user = User.find(params[@point.user_id])
  if @user && @user.increment(:points_balance, by = @point.points_moving)
  respond_to do |format| 
    format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Saved.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
  end
end
```

Let me know if that solves your issue.

You want `User`'s `point_balance` to increase, but you're incrementing `update_count`.

Comment: Would you check your rails server console for any errors. You may find something there. Please post the logs.

Comment: I checked the logs, didnt find anything. tks but cant post the logs.

Comment: yes, saw and tried that, didnt work. Still trying to figure it out. must be some type of typo.... cant get any errors either.

Comment: @Francisco, are you getting a response back(since its not updating user points), if not it must be raising an exception. Isn't it?

Comment: Im running the method that triggers the point creation and then I get the correct view of another object. I then check manually to see if points have been created into another view and they have. In that same view I can see :points_balance = 0

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114337/discussion-between-kumar-abinash-and-francisco).

Comment: Ok, how do i enter the chat?

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to paarticipate in chat.

Comment: Okay. Did you confirm in rails console that its not increasing the points?

Comment: could devise auth be messing up things? Im able to manually change user attr from forms but first time trying this way..

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using `@user.increment!(:update_count, by = @point.point_moving)`. Note the `!`, which causes it to update the database. Unlike your version which just updates the instance variable.

However, this can be very racy if you have multiple requests coming in at the same time incrementing the same user. So I would avoid this 'read and then write' approach, and do it directly in the database like so:

```
User.where(id: @user.id).
     update_all("update_count = update_count + #{@point.point_moving}")
```

Comment: tks but I tried both ways, and I cant get it to work.

Comment: Like others have questioned before, I'm not sure if you're trying to update the `update_count` attribute on the model or the `points_balance`. Try the above using `points_balance`.

Comment: This is strange. The only thing I can suggest is for you to then show me the updated snippet of code that you're using, and the log files.

Comment: Tks. Ive stopped trying this way, unless different approach. Im now waiting to get lucky and for someone to suggest a separate method with a call from the :create method.